# How do I show that these two vectors are dependent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $1<n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n >0$.

If $\frac{a_i}{\sum_j a_j}=\frac{b_i}{\sum_j b_j}$ for all $i$, how do I show that there exists $c>0$ such that $ca_i=b_i$ for all $i$?

I could easily prove this when $n=2$, but I am not sure how to show this for the case $n\neq 2$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that there is no typo in your question, however $\sum_j a_j=A$ and $\sum_j b_j=B$ are independent of $i$ and you simply have $c=\frac{B}{A}$, no?

Comment: Aha.. foolish me.. thank you!

Comment: no problem I have done such kind of things too :-), +1

Comment: @ViktorGlombik yes otherwise $A$ and $B$ would not be independent of $i$